# Unable to select an item in Nebula TableComboViewer on JFace TitleAreaDialog

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface, nebula

I am unable to select an item in TableCombo from Nebula when I use it on a Dialog but when I tried to use it on a Viewer it works just fine.

```
public class MyDialog extends TitleAreaDialog {
    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea( Composite parent ) {
        Composite area = (Composite) super.createDialogArea( parent );
        Composite container = new Composite( area, SWT.NONE );
        FillLayout fill = new FillLayout( SWT.VERTICAL );
        fill.marginHeight = 5;
        fill.marginWidth = 5;
        container.setLayout( fill );
        container.setLayoutData( new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true) );

        new MyTableComboViewer( container );
        return container;
    }

    private class MyTableComboViewer extends TableComboViewer {

        public MyTableComboViewer() {
            super( parent, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER | SWT.READ_ONLY );

            setContentProvider( new TableComboContentProvider() );
            setLabelProvider( new TableComboLabelProvider() );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but `createDialogArea` should be returning `area` not `container`.

Comment: @greg-449 yep, still same issue.